# AndroidViewClient: How to know we completely drag screen till the end

Tags: android, python-3.x, androidviewclient

I want to send a message to all friends using IDs, my screen show only 12 IDs at a time. here I'm collecting all IDs in a list and sending messages to all 12 IDs, now I'm clear the IDs list and dragging the screen. now pick up the new IDs.
So, I want to know that I have completely drag the screen till the end that I can terminate the outer loop.

```
name = list(vc.findViewsWithAttribute('class','javaClass'))
while True:
    for i in range(len(name)):
        try:
            vc.dump()
            name[i].touch()
            vc.dump()
            vc.findViewWithText('Chat').touch()
            new_message = message 
            vc.dump()
            message_field = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("com.snapchat.android:id/chat_input_text_field")
            message_field.setText(new_message)
            time.sleep(1)
            vc.dump()
            d.press("input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER")
            vc.dump()
            vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("com.snapchat.android:id/back_button").touch()
        except:pass
    try:
        name.clear()
        device.drag((200, 500), (200,180), 68, 20, 0)
        name = list(vc.findViewsWithAttribute('class','javaClass'))
    except: pass
```

I want to change **while True:** condition because It's an infinite loop.

Comment: Not sure if it's what you are asking, but you can take a look at "Fling to end" https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI#uiscrollable-submenu

Comment: How to know that I'm scrolled all IDs and I'm in the end after that there is no ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think that something like this should work

```
last_name = None
name = list(vc.findViewsWithAttribute('class','javaClass'))
while last_name != name[-1]:
    for i in range(len(name)):
        try:
            vc.dump()
            name[i].touch()
            vc.dump()
            vc.findViewWithText('Chat').touch()
            new_message = message 
            vc.dump()
            message_field = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("com.snapchat.android:id/chat_input_text_field")
            message_field.setText(new_message)
            time.sleep(1)
            vc.dump()
            d.press("input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER")
            vc.dump()
            vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("com.snapchat.android:id/back_button").touch()
        except:pass
    try:
        name.clear()
        device.drag((200, 500), (200,180), 68, 20, 0)
        last_name = name[-1]
        name = list(vc.findViewsWithAttribute('class','javaClass'))
    except: pass
```